# Translate an element with respect to right edge of the viewport

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a div which is initially translated out of the screen using this CSS

```
transform: translateX(100%);
```

Now, I want this div to translate back into the view port by a specific number of pixels from the right side. I have been using `transform: translateX(-450px)`, but it translates with respect to the origin of the viewport i.e (x,y) = (0,0). What I want instead is to bring the div 450px into the viewport from the right side of the screen.
In other words, I want my origin of translate to be `(x,y)=(100%,0%)` 
Is there anything which can be done to achieve this?

Comment: any downvote on a reasonable and valid question should provide a reason for doing so. If you can't then stop downvoting valid questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add multiple translate the transform CSS side by side.

```css
.box{
  transform: translateX(100%) translateX(-450px);

}
```